# How to check for pop up alert using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What I want is to continue with the next iteration if there is a pop up message in the webpage being scrapped. That is if there is any pop up message, I want to accept that message and go to the next item i.e go to the beginning of the loop.

For this I use the following snippet of code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import StringVar as sv
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


for(i in range(0,5)):
      try:
          click_alert=driver.switch_to_alert()
          click_alert.accept()

          continue
      except TimeoutException:
           print('wrong value in'+i+'th row . Please check the value ')
```

The following error shows up:

Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/chowdhuryr/Desktop/ATT RESEARCH BOT/GUI.py", line 64, in printMessage
    self.Scrapper(str1,str2)
  File "C:/Users/chowdhuryr/Desktop/ATT RESEARCH BOT/GUI.py", line 163, in Scrapper
    click_alert=driver.switchTo().alert()
```

Now I am pretty certain that the error lies in `click_alert=driver.switch_to_alert()` because I have checked it using some sanity checks.

Answer (score 3):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
browser.find_the_element_by_id("add_button").click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                   'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                   'confirmation popup to appear.')

    alert = browser.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("alert accepted")
except TimeoutException:
    print("no alert")
```